# Как с помощью средств C++ вызвать прерывание?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, прерывания

Сейчас использую:

```
#define int86(int) { asm volatile ("int $"#int ::: "memory"); }
```

Работает, но посреди разных `constexpr` и `inline` данная конструкция выглядит как анахронизм.
Предполагаю, что нужен шаблон вида `template< int I >void int86(){ asm volatile ( "int $???что здесь???":::"memory") }`, но как его соорудить не понимаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подразумевая, что это GCC-совместимая ассемблерная вставка, можно как-то так ([отрывок на godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/R3xNRL)):

```
template<int I>
void int86() { 
  asm volatile ( "int %0" :
                          : "i" (I) 
                          : "memory"); 
}
```

Это обычный синтаксис для передачи параметров в ассемблерную вставку. После второго двоеточия идут входные параметры. Ограничение `"i"` означает, что аргумент является целой константой времени компиляции.

Детали смотри в [документации gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C).

Comment: RTFM, как говорится. Такое решение даже шаблонов не требует. Благодарю.